# Swift: Where Is NSDragOperationNone?

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, drag, appkit

In Objective-C, I can return `NSDragOperationNone` from various drag/drop methods to indicate that I do not want to handle a given drag. This is listed explicitly in Apple's Docs for the Objective-C version of `NSDragOperation`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdragoperation?language=objc

However, if you view that page for Swift, or you look at the `NSDragOperation` definition in Apple's Swift headers, `.none` is not an option.

So...how do I decline a drag operation in Swift? In a method such as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> NSDragOperation
```

---

## NOTE:

1) I am explicitly dealing with AppKit and macOS, not UIKit or iOS.

2) I realize I can just init `NSDragOperation` with a rawvalue of `0`, which is the value given to `NSDragOperationNone` in Objective-C, but that's fragile. What is the Swift way of declining a drag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have realised this already, but `NSDragOperation` is a bit mask. The value of each case is a power of 2, and you are supposed to use `|` to mask them in Objective-C.

In Swift, `NSDragOperation` is bridged to conform to `OptionSet` and you can use them with a set-like syntax like this:

```
let dragOp: NSDragOperation = [.copy, .link]
```

So a `none` operation is just an empty set:

```
let dragOp: NSDragOperation = []
```

Comment: Thanks. The more I dive into Swift, the less I like it. A named "none" case is much more clear and the old Objective-C approach is superior for that reason. It's simple and fast to grok.

Answer (score 2):

Use [].
.none is deprecated. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65205